# Javascript does not work from button click

Tags: pdftex, miktex, 3d, media9, javascript

I have this very simple LaTeX file that uses the media9 package to insert 3D objects. I want to animate parts of the 3D object using Javascript, preferably on a button click.

My problem is that when I call my Javascript function through a TimeEventHandler or a MouseClickEvent, the animation works well. But when I create a `\mediabutton` to call the very same function, I get an error.

The following is a part of my LaTeX code (where `animate()` is a function defined in animation.js):

```
\includemedia[
    label=model,
    activate=pageopen,
    add3Djscript=animation.js
]{}{model.u3d}

\mediabutton[
    jsaction=model:{annotRM[`model'].context3D.animate();}
]{\fbox{Play Animation}}
```

Here is the simplest version of my JS code that still fails:

```
cube=scene.meshes.getByName("Cube");

function animate(){
    cube.visible=false;
}
```

While debugging, I found that I get the following error in JS and I have no idea why.

```
SyntaxError: illegal character
1:Field:Mouse Up
```

I even tried using media9's sample code and files, and I get the same error even though they should work perfectly. (The error only happens with the sample files that use `\mediabutton` with Javascript; the other samples work properly.)

I've been trying to figure out whether this was a problem with LaTeX or JS, and seeing that the JS code works perfectly as long as I don't use the button, I figured I'd try to find any solutions here.

No one else seems to have any problems attaching JS functions to media buttons. Any insight would be very much appreciated.

If it matters, I'm using MikTeX pdflatex.

Comment: `animation.js` which is part of the `media9` package doesn't define a function `animate()`.

Comment: Sorry if it was confusing. The animation.js file I mentioned here is my own, with an animate() function I defined. (The actual filename is different but I changed it here to be more understandable, but I guess that made you think I was referring to media9's animation.js)

Comment: Edited my question to include my JS code.

Comment: The leading backtick of `\`model'` is the character that JS complains about. Replace it with a single quote.

Comment: @AlexG Replacing it with a single quote worked. Thanks! When I type in TeXworks, the single quote gets turned to backticks automatically so I assumed that was correct.

Answer (score 2):

In order to play a keyframe animation embedded in a U3D file, `animation.js` defines a `TimeEventHandler` object `"myTimer"` that is added to the 3D `runtime` object. To pause the animation, this `TimeEventHandler` must be removed from the `runtime` object again. This can be implemented using `\mediabutton` as follows:

```
\mediabutton[
  jsaction=model:{
    cntxt3d=annotRM['model'].context3D;
    cntxt3d.runtime.removeEventHandler(cntxt3d.myTimer);
  }
]{\fbox{Pause Animation}}
\mediabutton[
  jsaction=model:{
    cntxt3d=annotRM['model'].context3D;
    cntxt3d.runtime.addEventHandler(cntxt3d.myTimer);
  }
]{\fbox{Play Animation}}
```